# Make new line without using <br> in HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to make each one of these element is different line, without using `<br />` in HTML, `<h1>` is block element but I have to fix its `width`. How can I make anchors come under `<h1>` not beside?

```
<h1 id="viewerTitle">Header </h1>
<a href="#" class="view-options">View options</a>
<a href="#" class="view-options">View options</a>
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/mmhhd/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Start by removing `float: left` from `h1`.

Then add the rule:

```
a.view-options {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Why is it the point? It doesn't change the width (setting the width does that); unless you want something to the right of the header, you shouldn't float it.

Answer (score 13):

Alternative way:

Remove `float:left;` in `h1` and `display: inline-block;` in `a.view-options`

Then add

```
h1:after, a:after {
    content:"\a";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/8my6q/

Answer (score 9):

Use CSS:

```
a {
  display: block;
}
```

By default `a` tag is an inline element, so you have to change its display property.

From the CSS specification:

> Block-level elements are those elements of the source document that are formatted visually as blocks (e.g., paragraphs). The following values of the 'display' property make an element block-level: 'block', 'list-item', and 'table'.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-boxes

> Inline-level elements are those elements of the source document that
>   do not form new blocks of content; the content is distributed in lines
>   (e.g., emphasized pieces of text within a paragraph, inline images,
>   etc.). The following values of the 'display' property make an element
>   inline-level: 'inline', 'inline-table', and 'inline-block'.
>   Inline-level elements generate inline-level boxes, which are boxes
>   that participate in an inline formatting context.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes

Answer (score 5):

Use CSS to make the anchor link tags blocks:

```
a.view-options { display: block; }
```

Comment: Try to modify the jsfiddle please, the anchor seems to go before the h1 !

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/mmhhd/2/ header is floated, so a clear is in order.

Answer (score 3):

Make the anchor tags block elements as well.

Answer (score 3):

Take float off the h1 tag and make a tags' display: `display: block;`

Answer (score 3):

This is the way that works for me.

```
p.autonewline {white-space: pre-line;}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! It makes html use the newlines in the text, like in textarea