# Content on new line without using BR

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve a simple layout like this:

```
Title at place----------Date
Location------------Complete
```

this is what I have now: http://jsfiddle.net/80m96ko3/2/

I want to have location and complete on the line below. Is the only way to achieve this to use a BR, unless I have to use a display block which will make the title link clickable across the entire width (which I don't want). I'd also rather not use a `<table>`.

```
<div class="job">
<span class="title">Title</span> at <span class="place">Place</span><span class="posted right">15 Jun</span>
<span class="location">Location</span><span class="type right">Complete</span>
</div>
```

Comment: use display block on your elements

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make new line without using <br> in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134439/make-new-line-without-using-br-in-html)

Answer (score 5):

You can use pseudo  class `:before` (*or :after*) to break a line.

```
.location:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Adding this code to the user's fiddle doesn't get the requested layout. Maybe I'm missing something, but I think it needs to be `.location:before` instead of `.title:after`

Comment: That's quite nice but it doesn't match the layout in the question, and in @web-tiki it drops it down a line on the right

Comment: Mr_Green's solution works fine for me, but I still see one line drop in Web-tiki's one

Answer (score 1):

Use a unordered list. It will do your job.

```
<ul class="job">
  <li>
    <span class="title">Title</span> at <span class="place">Place</span><span class="posted right">15 Jun</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="location">Location</span><span class="type right">Complete</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an unordered list?

```
<div class="job">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span class="title">Title</span> at <span class="place">Place</span><span class="posted right">15 Jun</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="location">Location</span><span class="type right">Complete</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And your styles:

```
.right {float: right;}
ul {list-style: none ;}
```

Comment: A list is ok, but seems a bit overkill for two lines?

Comment: Depends on your definition of overkill. Personally, I think using <br> makes the most sense, if you only have two lines...No?